# Pyramid Web Framework 1.6 - Simple multi page website

Tags: python, frameworks, pyramid

Hello I have just started to try out Pyramid 1.6a Im just trying to create a multipage site to try and get used to the framework.  Not sure what Im doing wrong but i cant get another page to render such as  0.0.0.0:1234/another-url i can only do 0.0.0.0:1234/.  Below is my starter that i created using pcreate -s starter ,

```
__init__.py    
from pyramid.config import Configurator


    def main(global_config, **settings):
        """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
        """
        config = Configurator(settings=settings)
        config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
        config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
        config.add_route('a', '/')
        config.add_route('b', '/b')
        config.add_route('c', '/c')
        config.scan()
        return config.make_wsgi_app()


    views.py    
    from pyramid.view import view_config
    from pyramid.renderers import render, render_to_response
    from pyramid.response import Response
    from pyramid.config import Configurator


    class MyView(object):
        def __init__(self, request):
            self.request = request


        @view_config(route_name='edit')
        @view_config(route_name='change')
        def edit(request):
            return Response('edited!')



        @view_config(route_name='a', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
        def a(self):
            self.title = 'Oliver Test a'
            return {'project': 'a'}


        @view_config(route_name='b', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
        def b(self):
            self.title = 'Oliver Test b'
            return {'project': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access only routes you have defined:

```
    config.add_route('a', '/')
    config.add_route('b', '/b')
    config.add_route('c', '/c')
```